# HMSegmentedControl react to tapping on currently selected segment

Tags: objective-c, ios, user-interface

I'm using HMSegmentedControl, an open-source UISegmentedControl subclass. I'm trying to react to the user tapping on the currently selected segment. HMSegmentedControl only supports reacting to a segment CHANGE, with either `UIControlEventValueChanged` or a block that executes when the index is changed. I need to react to the currently selected segment in order to present a drop-down menu. Here is what I've done so far:

```
-(void)segmentedControlValueChanged:(HMSegmentedControl *)control {
    CGFloat midX = self.view.frame.size.width / 2 - _filterView.frame.size.width / 2;
    _filterView.frame = CGRectMake(midX, -_filterView.frame.size.height+64, _filterView.frame.size.width, _filterView.frame.size.height);
    _filterView.hidden = YES;

    _filterBackgroundView.alpha = 0.0f;
    _filterBackgroundView.hidden = YES;
}

-(void)segmentedControlTouchUpInside:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gr {

    if(!_filterView) {
        _filterView = (HomeFilterView *)[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HomeFilterView" owner:self options:nil].firstObject;
        CGFloat midX = self.view.frame.size.width / 2 - _filterView.frame.size.width / 2;
        _filterView.frame = CGRectMake(midX, -_filterView.frame.size.height+64, _filterView.frame.size.width, _filterView.frame.size.height);
        _filterView.delegate = self;
        [self.view insertSubview:_filterView belowSubview:self.segmentedControl];
    }

    if(!_filterBackgroundView) {

        _filterBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
        _filterBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        _filterBackgroundView.alpha = 0.0f;
        [self.view insertSubview:_filterBackgroundView belowSubview:_filterView];
    }

    _filterView.hidden = NO;
    _filterBackgroundView.hidden = NO;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f delay:0.0f usingSpringWithDamping:0.55f initialSpringVelocity:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{

        CGFloat midX = self.view.frame.size.width / 2 - _filterView.frame.size.width / 2;
        CGFloat y = self.segmentedControl.frame.size.height + self.segmentedControl.frame.origin.y;
        _filterView.frame = CGRectMake(midX, y-70, _filterView.frame.size.width, _filterView.frame.size.height);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f animations:^{

        _filterBackgroundView.alpha = 0.5f;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}
```

I added a tap gesture recognizer to the segmented control. So, if a user selects the current segment, only `segmentedControlTouchUpInside:` will be fired. If a user selected a different segment, `segmentedControlTouchUpInside:` is fired, followed by `segmentedControlValueChanged:`. I'm relying on the `segmentedControlValueChanged:` method to be called after the gesture-recognizer method, and essentially "undo" the adding of the drop-down to the UI.

This is the only way I could figure out to handle the tapping of the current segment. It seems to accomplish what I'm going for in the UI, but can anyone think of a better way of doing this? Is this safe to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fork the control and do a tiny modification to the code to do what you need.

In `touchesEnded:withEvent:`, you need to modify [this line](https://github.com/HeshamMegid/HMSegmentedControl/blob/master/HMSegmentedControl/HMSegmentedControl.m#L624) so it wouldn't check if the tapped segment is the currently selected segment:

```
    if (segment < sectionsCount)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your response! Yes I actually found this line. I'm kinda unfamiliar with forking though. If I have the control integrated into my project via Cocoapods, will I be able to keep it that way if I fork it?

Comment: I figured it out. This SO question helped me integrate the forked repo via Cocoapods. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936885/cocoapods-and-github-forks